# Cannot convert type date to integer using liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to change date type in my Postgsql DB to integer one using this changeset :

```
--changeset Sihem:001
ALTER TABLE training 
  ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE integer USING end_date::integer;
```

But I got an error : could not convert type date to integer. Any idea please ?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Converting a date to an integer can be done in multiple ways.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A `date` is the proper data type to store date values.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  However, you could convert to, say, a number of days since some base date:

```
using extract(epoch from (end_date - '1970-01-01'::date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by:

```
 ALTER TABLE training
    ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE integer USING (EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM end_date));
```